# Read range Excel Sheet using OleDB

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I want to read from an excel file using OleDbDataReader

```
string con= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ruta + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [Template$A1:JB2435]", connection);
```

But when I run this code, this error shows in runtime

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Template$A1:JB2435'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly

If i don't put the range the program works, but I want to select a range from that Excel sheet

Comment: I guess you want to select from table with the name on [Template$A1:JB2435]? Right now you are selecting from the table named `[Template$A1:JB2435]` literally

Comment: Ok, so that's my mistake, but how can I select from the sheet "Template" the range from cell A1 to cell JB2435?

Comment: So do you want to select from 637970 diferent tables?

Comment: No, I want to select from just one table (which is on the sheet Template) and from that table select only from cell A1 to cell JB2435

Comment: The tableis the `Template` sheet or the name of the table is on the sheet? If the second, where on the sheet it is?

Comment: The table is in the Template sheet. The table hasn't got a name, there are just a bunch of rows wit the first row the header row

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. Apparently the Excel file has to be closed, if it's open it says that error...